# cq:emptyText is not working in Adobe CQ5.5

Tags: adobe, components, containers, aem

I'm developing a custom container component in Adobe CQ5.5 and I'd like to have a custom message as a placeholder instead of the default "Drag components or assets here".

What I found out until now is that I have to add cq:emptyText="My custom placeholder message". Probably I'm missing something as this property gets completely ignored. Here's my component's folder structrure:

- [clientlib]
- .content.xml
- _cq_editConfig.xml
- dialog.xml
- myContainer.jsp

According to [Adobe's official tutorials](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html) and also [this wonderful tutorial for building an Accordion container](http://jenikya.com/blog/2012/03/cq5-accordion-component.html), the cq:emptyText should go into the _cq_editConfig.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:actions="[edit]"
    cq:dialogMode="floating"
    cq:emptyText="Drag My Custom components here"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:listeners
        jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Unfortunately, even with cq:emptyText included I'm still seeing the default placeholder text.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Stan.

---

**UPDATE:**

After Tomek's suggestions, I still get "Drag components or assets here" instead of my custom message so I'm **still looking for an answer**. My component's file structure now looks like this:
- [clientlib]
- [new]
---- .content.xml
---- _cq_editConfig.xml
- .content.xml
- _cq_editConfig.xml
- dialog.xml
- tabContainer.jsp

**.content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:isContainer="{Boolean}true"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Tab Container"
    jcr:description="Container component for tab pages"
    sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/parsys"
    componentGroup="MyComponents"/>
```

**_cq_editConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:actions="[edit]"
    cq:dialogMode="floating"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:listeners
        jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"/>
</jcr:root>
```

**new/.content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="New Paragraph"
    sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys/new"
    componentGroup=".hidden"/>
```

**new/_cq_editConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:actions="[_clear,insert]"
    cq:emptyText="Drag My Custom components here"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig" />
```

Answer (score 4):

As you're implementing parsys, you need following structure, as Tomek Rękawek suggested:

**.content.xml** (*the important part here is the `resourceSuperType`*)

```
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:isContainer="{Boolean}true"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Your title"
    sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

**new/.content.xml**

```
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="New Paragraph"
    sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys/new"
    componentGroup=".hidden"/>
```

**new/_cq_editConfig.xml** (*this is where you would want to set the `cq:emptyText` attribute*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:actions="[_clear,insert]"
    cq:emptyText="Drag My Custom components here"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig"/>
```

At this moment I was not getting the "Drag My Custom components here" text on the component placeholder. What did the trick for me was to create `new/new.jsp` with following content:

**new/new.jsp**

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
%><%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"
%><%@ page session="false" import="
    com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.EditContext" %><%

    editContext.getEditConfig().setEmpty(true);
%>
```

Then I was able to see the empty text I set in `new/_cq_editConfig.xml`. I've tested this on CQ5.6.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added the new/new.jsp but with still no effect :-(. I'm running on 5.6.1 which means that maybe there is a setting somewhere that might have to be turned on. I'm using the exact same files as you do, but no result.

Comment: @stan, I'm running 5.6.1 this answer does worked for me

Comment: As I said, there might be something else that is preventing me from showing that text and eventually I stopped trying.

Answer (score 2):

This container is usually called *paragraph system* or *parsys*. You should have structure like this:

**.content.xml**

```
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:isContainer="{Boolean}true"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Your title"
    sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

**new/.content.xml**

```
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="New Paragraph"
    sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys/new"
    componentGroup=".hidden"/>
```

**new/_cq_editConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:actions="[_clear,insert]"
    cq:emptyText="Drag My Custom components here"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig"/>
```

So, you need to create `new` subdirectory to your component and the property should be added to the file `new/_cq_editConfig.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tomek. I did everything you suggested but I still see only the default "Drag your components or assets here". See my updates above for more info, I can't put everything here.